# Function to get the number of checked checked boxes within a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a `JQuery` function which will get the number of checked check boxes within a specific `div` which is passed through as an argument.

```
var max = 1;
function checkMax(e) {   
    var item = $("#" + e).html().find("input:checked");
    var checked = item > ":input:checked";   

    alert(item);    
}

if (item >= max){
preventDefault();
}
```

Also how can I prevent user to be able to check check box if maximum number of allowed check boxes has been checked already

Comment: Is `e` the id of the element?

Comment: `.html` will return a string.

Comment: Remove `html()` and then use `item.length`

Comment: Use `item = $("#" + e).find("input:checked");` and access number of elements by `item.length`.

Comment: how can I prevent them to check the check box when `if statement` is `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `:checked` element using `.find()` then use `length` property.

```
var item = $("#" + e).find("input:checked");
alert(item.length);
```

No need to use `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

As asked by OP, I have created a **function** that **accepts an element** and checks the content for checkboxes. In simple ways, you can do with a single selector:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    checkHowMany($(this).closest("div"));
    return false;
  });
  function checkHowMany($div) {
    var num = $div.find(".chk-box:checked").length;
    alert("There are " + num + " checked check boxes.");
  }
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
label {display: block;}
div {margin-bottom: 10px;}
a {display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; color: #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div class="section-1">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <a href="">Check how many checked in this Section.</a>
</div>
<div class="section-2">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <a href="">Check how many checked in this Section.</a>
</div>
<div class="section-3">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="chk-box"> Check Me</label>
  <a href="">Check how many checked in this Section.</a>
</div>
```

Here, the `<a>` calls the function with its parent `<div>` as the argument to be passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  getCheckedLength("container1")
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
getCheckedLength("container2")
});

function getCheckedLength(id) {
  var $div = $("#" + id);
  alert($("input[type='checkbox']:checked", $div).length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <input type="checkbox">1 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox">2 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox">3 &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <input type="checkbox">4 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox">5 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox">6 &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Get checked number form div 1">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Get checked number form div 2">
```

Comment: Please try using the snippet feature.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - sure..I havnt used it before, let me try updating

Comment: Press Ctrl + M. It's similar to JSFiddle. Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Done. Thanks dude...

Comment: Looks nice man.